# changing user and setting env variable

Tags: ansible

Using ansible im trying to 
1. sudo into a user id - hduser 
2. set some env variables 
3. source the file.

Later, I print the env variables but don't see the env variables being set for the user hduser

```
- name: change to hduser
  shell: sudo su - hduser

- name: Setting 
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /home/hduser/.bashrc 
    line: 'export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop' 
    insertafter: 'EOF' 
    regexp: 'export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop' 
    state: present

- name: Adding the path in the bashrc files
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /home/hduser/.bashrc 
    line: 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64' 
    insertafter: 'EOF' 
    regexp: 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64' 
    state: present

- name: Adding the path in the bashrc files
  lineinfile: 
    dest: /home/hduser/.bashrc 
    line: 'export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin' 
    insertafter: 'EOF' 
    regexp: 'export PATH=\$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin' 
    state: present

- name: Source the bashrc file
  shell: source /home/hduser/.bashrc 
  register: sourcevar
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- debug:
    var: sourcevar
- name: print env variables
  shell: sudo su hduser && env
  register: envvar
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- debug: 
    var: envvar
```

These are my env variables it does not list the ones I sourced.

```
ok: [default] => {
    "envvar": {
        "changed": true, 
        "cmd": "sudo su hduser && env", 
        "delta": "0:00:00.013310", 
        "end": "2017-09-15 17:37:01.913357", 
        "rc": 0, 
        "start": "2017-09-15 17:37:01.900047", 
        "stderr": "", 
        "stderr_lines": [], 
        "stdout": "TERM=xterm-256color\nSHELL=/bin/bash\nUSER=root\nSUDO_USER=vagrant\nSUDO_UID=1000\nUSERNAME=root\nMAIL=/var/mail/root\nPATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\nPWD=/home/vagrant\nLANG=en_US.UTF-8\nSHLVL=1\nHOME=/root\nSUDO_COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-nzuyqifbpqxknsapqpiflhxbmsrzdaqo; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505497021.78-205792997462616/command.py; rm -rf \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505497021.78-205792997462616/\" > /dev/null 2>&1\nLOGNAME=root\nSUDO_GID=1000\n_=/usr/bin/env", 
        "stdout_lines": [
            "TERM=xterm-256color", 
            "SHELL=/bin/bash", 
            "USER=root", 
            "SUDO_USER=vagrant", 
            "SUDO_UID=1000", 
            "USERNAME=root", 
            "MAIL=/var/mail/root", 
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin", 
            "PWD=/home/vagrant", 
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8", 
            "SHLVL=1", 
            "HOME=/root", 
            "SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-nzuyqifbpqxknsapqpiflhxbmsrzdaqo; /usr/bin/python /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505497021.78-205792997462616/command.py; rm -rf \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1505497021.78-205792997462616/\" > /dev/null 2>&1", 
            "LOGNAME=root", 
            "SUDO_GID=1000", 
            "_=/usr/bin/env"
        ], 
        "warnings": [
            "Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every task in Ansible is treated separately.

This way, this are two independent tasks:

```
- name: Source the bashrc file
  shell: source /home/hduser/.bashrc 
  register: sourcevar
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash

- name: print env variables
  shell: sudo su hduser && env
  register: envvar
```

And the second task knows nothing about the first one.

You should `source` and execute command in a single run:

```
- shell: source /home/hduser/.bashrc; env
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: The env variables are stiill are being printed.